# SELECT DISTINCT with JOIN is returning "manipulated" data

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have a SQL schema like this

"Exam" table

```
+--------------+----------+-------------+--------+
| EXAM_ID (PK) | PERSONID | DATEOFSTART | SECRET |
+--------------+----------+-------------+--------+
|            1 |      221 | 2016-01-24  |      0 |
|            2 |      221 | 2017-06-03  |      0 |
|            3 |      221 | 2016-09-17  |      1 |
+--------------+----------+-------------+--------+
```

"Exam_information" table

```
+---------------+------------------+---------+-------+
| PERSONID (PK) | DATEOFSTART (PK) | SUBJECT | SCORE |
+---------------+------------------+---------+-------+
|           221 | 2016-01-24       | Math    | A     |
|           221 | 2017-06-03       | Biology | B     |
|           221 | 2016-09-17       | Math    | C+    |
+---------------+------------------+---------+-------+
```

So exams can have additional information in `Exam_information` table. I know this isn't properly designed schema, but I can't modify it.

Ultimately I want to know all scores of a person where the exam is NOT a secret. I will build my DML a little by little, but let's start with a basic `JOIN` operation.

```
SELECT ei.*
FROM exam_information ei
INNER JOIN exam e
ON ei.personid = e.personid
WHERE ei.personid = 221
```

This will return 9 rows of data (because of cartesian join / cross join) so let's use `DISTINCT` in our `SELECT` statement.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ei.*
FROM exam_information ei
INNER JOIN exam e
ON ei.personid = e.personid
WHERE ei.personid = 221
```

This will return 3 rows of data so we seem to be on right track. We know that one of those returned 3 lines is secret and want to exclude that. Final version of DML is created.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ei.*
FROM exam_information ei
INNER JOIN exam e
ON ei.personid = e.personid
WHERE ei.personid = 221
AND e.secret = 0
```

Somehow (I'm not a SQL master by any means) this returns the same rows as previous DML. Three. Not two like I thought.

If I add `secret` field into my previous `SELECT` statement `SELECT DISTINCT e.secret, ei.* FROM ...` I will see that all the 3 returned rows have an zero as an value of secret which isn't true at all.

I've tried all kind of things, but nothing seem to work.

Comment: why `EXAM_ID` isnt part of `Exam_information`? You are right this is very bad design.

Comment: Look at your final query *without* the distinct. That still gets 6 rows back - you've eliminated 3, but they were all duplicates anyway?

Comment: As the answers suggest you should `JOIN` by `DATEOFSTART`  but this assume one student **CAN'T** have more than one exam a single day. And by my experience that isn't true. Also there isnt any reason why `exam_information` field need to be in a different table, they should be on the `exam` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're joining EACH record in exam_information to all 3 in exam, so even if you exclude the ONE that IS secret, it still detects the other 2 records, making for 6 records, that get returned distinctly as 3. You're missing a criteria for that JOIN (being the dateofstart), which matches each record in exam_information to a SINGLE record in exam, allowing the WHERE filter to work properly.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ei.*
FROM exam_information ei
INNER JOIN exam e
ON ei.personid = e.personid AND ei.dateofstart = e.dateofstart 
WHERE ei.personid = 221
AND e.secret = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your join is partial  the relation return alway 3 rows because   the distinct for this  return 3 rows

```
  ON ei.personid = e.personid
  WHERE ei.personid =
```

if you want only the rows with secret  0 you must link the single row using dateofstart

```
  SELECT DISTINCT ei.*
  FROM   exam_information ei
  INNER JOIN exam e
  ON ei.personid = e.personid and ei.DATEOFSTART  = e.DATEOFSTART 
  WHERE ei.personid = 221
  AND e.secret = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This this:

```
SELET DISTINCT ei.* FROM EXAM_INFORMATION ei
INNER JOIN
(SELECT PERSON_ID, DATEOFSTART FROM EXAM WHERE SECRET = 0) a
ON a.PERSON_ID = ei.PERSON_ID and ei.DATEOFSTART = a.DATEOFSTART
WHERE ei.PERSON_ID = 221;
```

The inner table will select all exam data that has no secret.  Then you perform a select on the info table, join it the inner table--this will give you all exam info for non-secret exam data, then lastly filter on the person_id.